# Play Framework + Docker : Database 'default' needs evolution

Tags: database, docker, playframework

We are using docker containers to manager our play application.

Database has its container and the application also.

Since a couple of days we are having this issue : "Database 'default' needs evolution!" when starting the application.

Here is the full log :

```
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: 2016-10-24 11:17:06.531 - [ESC[33mwarnESC[0m] - play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions - Run with -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true and -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApplyDowns=true if you want to run them automatically, including downs (be careful, especially if your down evolutions drop existing data)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: Oops, cannot start the server.
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: @71o5d24ai: Database 'default' needs evolution!
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:68)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.withLock(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:98)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.play$api$db$evolutions$ApplicationEvolutions$$runEvolutions(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:49)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions$$anonfun$start$1.apply(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.start(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:42)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutions.<init>(ApplicationEvolutions.scala:149)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get$lzycompute(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:53)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.db.evolutions.ApplicationEvolutionsProvider.get(EvolutionsModule.scala:44)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.provision(BoundProviderFactory.java:72)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.BoundProviderFactory.get(BoundProviderFactory.java:62)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1103)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:145)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:205)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator$1.call(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.loadEagerSingletons(InternalInjectorCreator.java:199)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.injectDynamically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:180)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:110)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:73)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:126)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:93)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:52)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:27)
Oct 24 11:17:06 tqfftg61s docker/7d8af1375733[1336]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart.main(ProdServerStart.scala)
```

In our conf file we have this :

```
# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply = true

# You can disable evolutions if needed
# play.evolutions.enabled=false

# You can disable evolutions for a specific datasource if necessary
# play.evolutions.db.default.enabled=false
```

It is the first time we have this problem. Could someone help me find what is going wrong ? 
Thanks

Comment: Did your current evolutions script get modified (maybe because of a recent merge) for this deployment? If so, you may also need to configure `play.evolutions.db.default.autoApplyDowns=true`.  As the output suggests, you just need to think about the impacts of applying downs if this results in data loss in your prod. environment.

Comment: I don't know how they run the application on the server. But this had to work since a long time before I started working with the team.
We did not upgrade the version of playframework.

Comment: did you rebuild the images?

Comment: No, i've finally figured out that one member of the team has modified a migration file that has already been executed by Play.

So I reverted his modification and created a new migration file.